# Does an initialization vector have to be saved for decryption?

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I'm working on text encryption using AES. I'm saving the key and encrypted text in files, but what should i do with IV?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The IV is usually stored with the ciphertext. Prefixing the IV is commonplace as you need the IV at the start when performing decryption. As the IV is *usually* one block in size, you do not have to store the size of the IV if you know the block cipher used. Beware that AES-GCM, a popular authenticated mode of encryption, is most effective with a 12 byte IV.

Note that the IV is binary and often consist of randomized bytes. Neither the IV nor the ciphertext are likely to consist of valid characters. You need a encoding format such as base 64 or - less commonly - hexadecimals **if** you need to store the IV and ciphertext as text.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you must provide the same IV for encryption and decryption.