# Does the initalization vector need to be kept, to decrypt data?

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes

I am trying to understand how I can encrypt a string with a passphrase, save it (for instance in a file) and decrypt it later **with a different application**.

I am following this example: https://attacomsian.com/blog/nodejs-encrypt-decrypt-data#encrypt-and-decrypt-text

I am confused about the "initialization vector". Does the application that decrypts the data need the same vector? So does it need to be stored with the data?

For example if I do this:

```
const algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr'
const secretKey = 'vOVH6sdmpNWjRRIqCc7rdxs01lwHzfr3'

const encrypt = text => {
  const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16)

  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, secretKey, iv)

  const encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(text), cipher.final()])

  return {
    iv: iv.toString('hex'),
    content: encrypted.toString('hex')
  }
}

const encryptedContent=encrypt("somethingsecret").content
writeFileSync("somefile.txt", encryptedContent))
```

it will save the encrypted data to "somefile.txt".

Is it then possible for a different application to decrypt the "somefile.txt" contents, **without** the initialization vector that was created during the encryption?

Comment: Yes, decryption must use the IV from encryption, so the (random) IV must be passed along with the ciphertext to the decrypting side, usually concatenated: iv|ciphertext (note that the IV is not a secret), s. e.g. this SO post [*Does an initialization vector have to be saved for decryption?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24219944/9014097).

Comment: *...how I can encrypt a string with a passphrase...* Note that `createCipheriv()` requires a *key* instead of a *passphrase*. If that's not a typo, i.e. if you you really want to use a passphrase, you should apply a key derivation function (e.g. PBKDF2) in conjunction with a *random* salt (which, analogous to the IV, must also be given to the decrypting side).